# How to copy a char array / String a variable number of times C++

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation

## Question:

in C++ : Given the std::string s = "copyme" how can I make a string b which is "copymecopymecopyme" or any generalized s + s + ... n times?

---

#### possible solutions

A possible solution would be a method/macro that does a for loop, but that would be horribly inefficient.

What is an efficient method of doing this string copy operation, e.g. as the previous author says in the style of 'string'*n in python or ruby.

a relatively efficient loop would be allocating strlen*n and then copying the chars over multiple times rather than for(...) {str+=copy_this_string;} which does multiple copies and allocates.

another solution is using a stringbuffer.

---

#### SO clarifications

key: *without* using a macro.
clarification: the 'char array' in the question is because in the original question, due to a single char in the string, all answers ignored the copying of a general stream and focused on using '.' since it had easily accessible methods such as the stream constructor.

"Duplicate" : [How to repeat a string a variable number of times in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166630/how-to-repeat-a-string-a-variable-number-of-times-in-c)
Except most the answers all used methods that only had a char repeated, e.g. the String Constructor and insert methods, which did not answer the original question and were unhelpful when I then looked for an efficient method.

Comment: How would a loop be inefficient?  How else could it possibly be implemented?

Comment: Don't be angry when everyone gives you the actual answer and it isn't what you hoped for.

Comment: Regarding your recent edit - do you really think that `'string'*n` is not a loop in its implementation?

Comment: both of you used +=. tell me when that has ever been efficient and I will upvote your answers. @CaptainSkyhawk

Comment: It was efficient yesterday morning, and five minutes ago.

Comment: += is more than good enough. You're shaving a yak.

Comment: yes because queues should recopy their values every time you append, that's efficient.

Comment: I don't see why this question was at -2 points; I +1'ed it as this is exactly a question I had a moment before, and the accepted answer seems to be very valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're worried about the string '+=' operation being inefficient, one optimization you can make is to reserve memory in the target string container.  This may avoid inefficient re-allocations of memory.
For example:

```
std::string s = "copyme";
std::string b;
target.reserve(s.length()*5);
for (int index = 0; index < 5; ++index)
{
    b += s;
}
```

I checked the std::string implementation on my linux system and it appears this method will not cause re-allocation of the array as long as the initial reservation is large enough.

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::
append(const basic_string& __str)
{
    const size_type __size = __str.size();
    if (__size)
    {
        const size_type __len = __size + this->size();
        if (__len > this->capacity() || _M_rep()->_M_is_shared())
            this->reserve(__len);
        _M_copy(_M_data() + this->size(), __str._M_data(), __size);
        _M_rep()->_M_set_length_and_sharable(__len);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: used for copying into it rather than copying from it. but yes this is more efficient as it reduces allocations +1.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop would do. If you are concerned about re-allocations, you can call `std::string::reserve` on the copy string:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const int num + 5;
  std::string s = "copyme";
  std::string b;
  b.reserve(s.size() * num); // reserve space for num* "copyme"
  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) b += s;

  std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf what is the backend array? State your requirements clearly.