# string Multiplication in C++

Tags: c++, string, multiplication, repeat

There is already a question for this here: [How to repeat a string a variable number of times in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/166630/2642059) However because the question was poorly formulated primarily answers about *character* multiplication were given. There are two correct, but expensive answers, so I'll be sharpening the requirement here.

---

Perl provides the `x` operator: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators which would let me do this:

```
$foo = "0, " x $bar;
```

I understand that I can do this with the helper functions such as those in the other answer. I want to know can I do this without my own helper function? My preference would be something that I could initialize a `const string` with, but if I can't do that I'm pretty sure that this could be answered with a standard algorithm and a lambda.

Comment: The short answer is: nope.

Comment: "standard algorithm and a lambda" - how is that not a helper function? please clarify. what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I think these parts go together "do this without my own helper function" - "if I can't do that I'm pretty sure that this could be answered with a standard algorithm and a lambda"

Comment: @JamesAdkison: Which makes the whole question vague.

Comment: So you want to know how to do this without a helper function but if you can't then you want to know how to do this in a "standard" way?

Comment: Do you want to avoid creating a temporary string for the initialization of the const string?

Comment: Maybe op wants a custom multiplication operator for `std::string`?

Comment: There's not a whole lot of difference between functions and lambdas. Why exactly lambdas are OK but functions are not?

Comment: @n.m. You're correct. This is really a code beautification thing, I wouldn't normally write a function for something that is only used in one location, so I'm trying to avoid it here as well.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Sounds a very useful proposition. However my preference here is something simple, cause I'm only using it in one place, I'd like everything to fit on one line ideally.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's correct, though it seems that I had trouble communicating that. I wish I could do this in C++: `const auto foo = "0, "s x bar;` But since I can't, and presuming there isn't a `string` constructor for this I want to do it in a standard function.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath This is a code beautification question primarily. I don't want to write a function that I only use in one place. And while what I really want to do is, `const auto foo = "0, "s x bar;` I'd settle for a non-`const` `foo` that is initialized in a standard function with a lambda.

Comment: @JonathanMee: use any existing code from the question you've linked.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath What are you suggesting here, none of the answers to the question I link accomplish this without writing my own function?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath They all do... what? Require me to write my own function? Perhaps you intended as is mentioned in [Simon Kraemer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35507367/2642059) that I just use these functions as lambdas?

Comment: *sigh* They all work fine without writing your own function. I'm off.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Got it, you're saying I could just write the functions directly into my code, which wouldn't really get this done in a single line or beautify the code, so it wouldn't make a good answer, but I suppose I could see how looking at that as a valid answer could make the question unclear.

Comment: single line? irrelevant. beautiful? definitely. it's clean code. get your priorities right.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath While I appreciate and understand your opinion. Code beauty and minimal length are irrelevant but if we can speak in terms of simplicity, readability, and maintainability, I think a better answer could be reached. I realize those are all subjective, but I do think I've got a good answer I'll post shortly...

Comment: well, @SimonKraemer 's answers are really ugly. They are needlessly complicated.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Though it wasn't exactly what I wanted, I did appreciate his multiplication operator, the rest of the code... could be improved. Though I have to say, it hardly seems fair for you to criticize his answers till you've written a better way to solve this.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Most of the linked answers are about repeating a single character. Only [**one**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34321702/4181011) is about repeating a complete string. I don't take any offense that my answers are *"really ugly"* and *"needlessly complicated"* but would you mind telling me what exactly bothers you about them? The linked answer is far more complicated.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I also agree that it is unecessary to use a lambda function when it is only used in one place. It would be far easier to just write the code in place.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: introducing an operator that's going to be used in one place in the whole codebase? tell me how's that sound.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Depends on the use case. If I can foresee that it will be used in multiple places in the future I think it's legit. Also if it improves readability. Whether to write it as operator function, lambda function or whatelse is just some kind of preference.

Answer (score 3):

You can either override the multiplication operator

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


std::string operator*(const std::string& str, size_t times)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < times; i++) stream << str;
    return stream.str();
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "Hello World!";
    size_t times = 5;

    std::string repeated = s * times;
    std::cout << repeated << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

... or use a lambda ...

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "Hello World!";
    size_t times = 5;

    std::string repeated = [](const std::string& str, size_t times) {std::stringstream stream; for (size_t i = 0; i < times; i++) stream << str; return stream.str(); } (s, times);
    std::cout << repeated << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

... or use a lambda with reference capturing ...

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "Hello World!";
    size_t times = 5;

    std::string repeated = [&s, &times]() {std::stringstream stream; for (size_t i = 0; i < times; i++) stream << str; return stream.str(); }();
    std::cout << repeated << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Instead of using `std::stringstream` you could also use `std::string` in combination with `std::string::reserve(size_t)` as you already know (or can calculate) the size of the result string.

```
std::string repeated; repeated.reserve(str.size() * times);
for (size_t i = 0; i < times; i++) repeated.append(str);
return repeated;
```

This might be faster: Compare http://goo.gl/92hH9M with http://goo.gl/zkgK4T

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this using just a standard algorithm and a lambda with [`generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n), but it still cannot initialize a `const string` it needs to be done in a separate line:

```
string foo;
const auto bar = 13U;

generate_n(back_inserter(foo), bar * 3U, [](){
    static const char multiplicand[] = "0, ";
    static const auto length = strlen(multiplicand);
    static auto i = 0U;
    return multiplicand[i++ % length];});
```

I've created a live example here: http://ideone.com/uIt2Ee But as is probably been made plain by all the question comments, the requirement of doing this in a single line results in inferior code. Right off the bat, we can see that the bare constant, `3`, represents the size of `multiplicand` and unnecessarily requires changes to the initialization of `multiplicand` to also update this literal.

The obvious improvement that should be made is:

```
string foo;
const auto bar = 13U;
const char multiplicand[] = "0, ";
const auto length = strlen(multiplicand);

generate_n(back_inserter(foo), bar * length, [&](){
    static auto i = 0U;
    return multiplicand[i++ % length];
});
```

The next improvement would be eliminating the reallocation as `foo` grows, which could be expensive if `bar` or `length` is large. That can be accomplished by constructing `foo` with sufficient space to contain the entire generated string:

```
const auto bar = 13U;
const char multiplicand[] = "0, ";
const auto length = strlen(multiplicand);
string foo(bar * length, '\0');

generate_n(foo.begin(), bar * length, [&](){
    static auto i = 0U;
    return multiplicand[i++ % length];
});
```

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/YrkkD7)]

Comment: `string::reserve` instead of the resize at construction would avoid to initialize `foo` twice.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ummm... I don't call either `reserve` or `resize`. Are you talking about my construction argument that `calloc`s `foo`: `string foo(bar * length, '\0');`?

Comment: Yes, I talked about `string foo(bar * length, '\0')`. To be replaced by `string foo; foo.reserve(bar * length);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not sure if I follow why it wouldn't be preferable to `calloc` this up front. Wouldn't that cause `foo` to be `malloc`ed and then `realloc`ed, since a `string` must always contain at least 1 `char` (the terminating NULL.)

Comment: There is still small string optimization, so I expect only one allocation for `reserve`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Hmmm, fair point. So you're saying that since we can't guarantee that the compiler will `calloc`, it may `malloc` and assign each element, in which case it'll be doing all those assignments twice, but only once if we just use reserve. I think I agree with that. I'll edit when I wrap up  the linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35580152/2642059