# How to print a character or string in multiple times in c++

Tags: c++, string

I have a my code that's look like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int x;
   char chars = '*';
   cin >> x;

   for (int i=1; i<=x; i++){
       cout << chars * i << endl;
  }


    cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and it compiled succesfully but, when I run it i just display this

```
1
42
```

and I want to print ('*') in x times, please someone help me

Comment: `char ` is treated as `int`.

Comment: See the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166630/how-to-repeat-a-string-a-variable-number-of-times-in-c

Comment: `cout << string(x, '*') << "\n";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int x;
   char chars = '*';
   cin >> x;

   for (int i=1; i<=x; i++){
       cout << chars;
  }

    cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments - `char` when multiplied by `int` results in `int`.

Is below code what you wanted?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x;
  char const chars = '*';
  std::cin >> x;

  for (int i=1; i<=x; i++) std::cout << chars << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```